# Display an alert error with php and javascript not working properly in FF and Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, firefox, alert

I use this piece of code to inform user to fill some field in this way:

```
ob_start();  
$msg = $_SESSION['ErrorUser'];

if($msg !=""){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" ' . $msg . '");</script>';
}

//echo $msg;
$_SESSION['ErrorUser']  = "";                 
ob_end_flush();
```

This works in Internet explorer while in FF and Chrome. The msg is displayed, but I have nothing in background, just a part of my page is showed (behind my Message alert).

Comment: Try to check if $msg contains any double quotes.

Comment: why would you want to take the control till server for simple validation ? validation things should be kept at client side itself, it reduces the server traffic and improves user interaction.

Comment: It sounds like the alert window appears before the page has completed loading. At which point is the alert initiated?

Comment: @dreamweiver, always do your validation primarily on the server side due to security. Client side is just an improvement of the user experience on top of that.

Comment: @DavidMulder:It depends on how much traffic does that create for mere form validation, like checking for empty data or valid data(email etc.,).

Comment: @dreamweiver there is not alternative to do validation on server side. you can do validation on clientside for a better experience. but server side validation would also allow non-javascript users fill out your form (and get an message!)

Comment: @tecjam: ya applicable based on the scenario :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that your outputting the alert straight into your dom which will cause the alert to be triggered while the dom is still loading. If you're using jQuery you should output the alert box inside the `jQuery(document).ready` callback or otherwise bind to the `load`/`DOMcontentready` events of the window object.

Comment: to be more detailed: calling alert() will block loading until the alert box is closed. if you are not using jquery or other framework you can use the onload-event or simply write the alert() at the end of your document

Comment: And How I can display this alert in Jquery?

Comment: You can't display in alert *in* jQuery, you can call the alert function in a specific jQuery callback, for example the aforementioend `jQuery(document).ready(callback)` callback.